# Google Data Studio / Looker - obtain correct values from a calculated field

Tags: looker-studio

**1) Data** I have a following dataset in google sheets (below is only a sample)
[LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zWBQaraQrYZJJsM-XXumTaSIN7L5q-bGUTJJn4-NhzA/edit?usp=sharing)

| Linie | Datum | Schicht | STD_Laufleistung | Kategorie | Dauer_min_net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 5,000.00 | 01 Durchlauf | 129 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 5,000.00 | 02 Downtime | 21 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 6,000.00 | 01 Durchlauf | 231 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 6,000.00 | 02 Downtime | 17 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 6,000.00 | 02 Downtime | 30 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Früh | 6,000.00 | 02 Downtime | 52 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Nacht |  | 02 Downtime | 320 |
| L1 | 01/09/2022 | Spät | 5,000.00 | 01 Durchlauf | 287 |

**2) Expected output table and desired output**

a) I would like to create a scorecard that shows which shifts are not balanced. (delta<>0). I have 5 types of shifts (Fruh, Spat, Nacht, Samstag, Sonntag)

- For Fruh, Spat, Nacht - each shift time (dauer_min_net) should be 480 per day
- For Samstag, Sonntag - here i have only one shift per day (dauer_min_net) and each should be 1440 per day

Scorecard should display: **8**

b) in the pivot table, delta should be showing 0 for shifts that are balanced

**3) Chart: Configuration + Setup**

I have created a simple scorecard and pivot table.
Additionaly, I created a alculating field:

```
CASE

WHEN Schicht in ("Samstag","Sonntag")

THEN

Dauer_min_net-1440

ELSE
Dauer_min_net-480

END
```

**4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output and 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4.**

In my Google Data Studio / Looker [LINK](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c803dfdc-3fee-457d-8b86-f57ecb19b3e9) unfortunately I I failed to obtain correct values. I assume it's due to the fact that I did not use in the formula SUM (x)... But I can't mix metrics and fields...

In the dashboard you can see all my attempted work - a scorecard and the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added solution to your [dashboard page 2](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/c803dfdc-3fee-457d-8b86-f57ecb19b3e9/page/p_x1vma87n0c)

Created a blend and added calculated fields

scorecard formula:

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Schicht, "Früh|Nacht|Spät")AND Dauer_min_net !=480 THEN 1
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Schicht, "Samstag|Sonntag")AND Dauer_min_net !=1440 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
 END
```

pivot formula:

```
Dauer_min_net-
(CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Schicht, "Früh|Nacht|Spät")THEN 480
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Schicht, "Samstag|Sonntag")THEN 1440
 END)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the prompt reply and working solution! Can you please in few words explain what you did and why it was not working for me? (e.g. why blend here is necessary, never thought it might be useful here)

Comment: this should be helpful (https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9429470)

Comment: Hey, could you also please tell me how I can filter out (i.e. exclude from the pivot), shifts that show 0 delta? I would simply like to see the 8 shifts that are in the scorecard only, and disregard those balanced.

Comment: not ideal but added a workaround in page 3 to showcase just the 8 results in table.